# Как передать часть массива в качестве параметра методу?

Tags: java

Имеется массив:

```
 array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Имеется метод:

```
public static void getArray(int[] array){
//тут что-нибудь делается с массивом, например просто выведем на печать
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++
    System.out.print(array[i] + " ");}
```

Интересует вопрос:
Как передать часть массива array в метод getArray?
Если сделать так:

```
getArray(array)
```

на печать выведется весь массив array.
А если я хочу, чтобы в метод передался массив начиная со 2-ой позиции (числа 3,4,5)

Comment: Создайте новый массив для этого

Comment: [Get only part of an Array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11001720/312041)

Comment: Нашёл решение - нужно в методе добавить принимаемые параметры, а именно - начало границы и конец границы массива, например:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл решение - нужно в методе добавить принимаемые параметры, а именно - начало границы и конец границы массива, например:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] mass, int firstElement, int lastElement, int searchElement){..}
```

Comment: отметьте галочкой свой ответ, если он вам подходит) чтобы вопрос считался отвеченным и не выскакивал у тех, кто ищет вопросы.

Answer (score 3):

Можно просто создать новый массив, в него передать нужные элементы и отдать в метод. К примеру, поступим как в вашем варианте и передадим последние 3 элемента.

```java
int[] newArray = new int[3];
System.arraycopy(array, 2, newArray, 0, 3);
getArray(newArray);
```

Comment: Лучше все же создавать другой массив, иначе в методе нужно валидировать параметры